# table design for small and medium relations in RDBMS with json column type

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

What is the current preferred way to design small and medium relations in RDBMS with container like column type (eg JSON, HSTORE, ARRAY ...). Eg Postgres have all this types.

Details:
I want to design a table layout for two sets: `A` and `B`. Let's consider relation `R: A x B`. We can implement that relation with table C in at least two ways:

1. `CREATE TABLE shopping (a int, b int)` - standard relation implementation using SQL. To get all `b-s` for given `a` with details of `a` and `b`  and product details we need to select multiple rows and join them with `A` and `B` table.
2. `CREATE TABLE shopping (a int, bs JSON)` - here we use a compound field `bs`. The advantage is that we select only one row to get all `b-s` for given `a` and we join it with one `a` row and multiple `b` rows.

Now let's consider more deeply the spec of relation `R`

1. Small relations, For all `a`: `max |{(a,b) \in Rs}| < 100`. Eg: DB of a small online shop, `A` - users, `B`: products, `R`: user shopping.
2. Medium relation, For all `a`: `max |{(a,b) \in Rs}| < 10000`, Eg: DB of a medium social portal `A` - user, `B`- posts, `R`: user-posts likes.
3. Like in 2. , `R`: Posts user-comments. Here i think the best way will be to not create tablee B, and store the content directly next to the posts using `ARRAY`.

Assuming I will use Postgresql 9.4, I'm wondering what's the best way to design this relation. For me it seems that for small and small-medium (`max` form examples above < 1000) relations compound fields form Postgresql should be faster and more pragmatic. Can anyone share his experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing I can tell you is that if your data is structured in an exact way, then I'd be much more apt to use standard SQL over JSON. JSON has tricky issues when it comes to updating or deleting parts of a JSON object, and until 9.4 I'd hold off entirely on making any sweeping table changes from a standard RDBMS (non Json) layout with multiple tables.

Another thing of note is that json objects are going to be larger in that you query the entire object all at once instead of joining and getting just what you want. Filtering isn't nearly as easy. I think that trying to eliminate joins by storing things in JSON isn't going to speed anything up and is certainly going to introduce complexities in update statements.

For me, I put in unstructured data into json, or data that has too may variations to implement in a sane way using standard data types-- even then, I usually break up the json into several smaller json objects so I can use a "where" statement on them.

Consider the following setup.
{ user:
       first_name : "joe",
       last_name : "blow",
       phones:[ 1 : [type : "landline",
                     num: "223-456-7890"
                    ],
                2:  [type : "cell"
                     num: "999-999-9999"
                    ],
                3:  [type : "cell"
                     num: "888-999-1234"
                    ]
              ]
}

forgive my syntax errors, I'm just trying to show an data structure here.

Now, you could represent this as a user table with user_id and details::json columns, or you could do a user table with first/last name columns and a second user_phones table.

If you do the JSON method, if you decide to update or delete phone, you're going to have to basically query the json object, manipulate it inside your app, then save the entire json object again-- likely your objects could become much larger than the one I mentioned above, and if your app mucks something up, you just might lose all the data for that user.

Secondly, imagine if I want to get a list of all cell phones from the DB along with the first and last name (I'm going to send a text message).

With traditional sql, it's simply

```
select *
from users u join user_phone up on up.user_id=u.user_id
where up.type='cell';
```

To do that within a query (and not writing it in your app)

```
select fname, lname, prec->>num
from(
    select data->>'first_name' fname, 
           data->>'last_name' lname, 
           json_each(data->'phones') as prec
    from users) u
where prec->>type='cell'
```

Ugly. Not to mention it's probably very slow.

Don't just jump in using JSON like that unless you consider how the queries and update statements are going to look.

On a side note,to make programming somewhat easier, I've made some of my data into json objects using views so the data is structured more like the objects I'll eventually want-- the SQL is still ugly writing the views, but the sql in the app is very pretty -- although performance considerations still override using that method in every case.

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming Postgres 9.4. You can easily write a function to manipulate json: https://gist.github.com/matheusoliveira/9488951. But I see your point. I think using standard SQL is good when you can pay for joins (extra performance hit). What about `ARRAY` type? Can you share some thoughts?

Comment: I'll write some more when I get some more time this evening, but please don't think of "paying" for joins -- they're very, very cheap in a database that's designed well and makes good use of indexes. The "query runtime" price for a join is almost zero compared to storing the objects in json, which (expecially without jsonb) have to be decoded which is more CPU overhead.

Comment: As for editing JSON, you still have to rewrite the entire object instead of just updating the specific piece, which is likely to slow down, as well as potentially introduce more lock contention

Comment: tbh I didn't test JSON (stored as jsonb) performance comparing to JOINs. It's really surprising that JOINs are faster then querying jsonb. So, @Joe, reading your answer I have an impression that unless someone has totally unstructured objects to query, he should always use std SQL?